# Аналог запроса RedBean на PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здравствуйте!!!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данный метод на обычном PDO? без данной ORM.

```
public function save($table)
{

   $tbl = \R::dispense($table);

   foreach($this->attributes as $name=>$value)
   {
     $tbl->name = value;
   }

   return \R::store($tbl);

}
```

Comment: вы представляете как конечный SQL запрос для этого выглядит? `update table1 set field1= value1, field2=value2` наверное? в чем именно проблема у вас возникает? как составит такой запрос по переданным имени таблицы и массиву полей-значений?

Comment: Его задача записать юзера в таблицу. Метод save() должен выполнить проверку. Мне не понятно как это записать все без орм.

Comment: if($user->save('user'))
            {
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Вы зарегистрированы!';
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Ошибка попробуйте снова!';
            }

Comment: коли регистрация то `insert into users ... `. Но вам нужно проверить, что такой пользователь отсутствует. Можно пойти двумя путями, проверить наличие в таблице вручную. И второй - повесить ограничение уникальности на поле (логина, видимо),  отловить ошибку при вставке.

Comment: сделал уникальными поля в таблице, я вот не пойму как $tbl( $tbl = \R::dispense($table);) объектом сделать у меня массив.